# triple cross prouct of tensor

Tags: python, computational-physics, eigenvalues, tensor

Im trying to compute a triple cross product of vectors a,b, and c in real space and integrate over the entire space. The result is a term in the hamiltonian for an electronic system so there are indices for the band number too (you can think of a and b as gradient of wavefunctions in real space and of c as a vector field):
$$
h_{nm} = \int \boldsymbol{a}_n(x)\times\boldsymbol{c}(x)\times\boldsymbol{b}_m(x)\,d x
%![equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeGe3.gif)
$$
where $n$ and $m$ are indices from i.e. 0 to 50. I can write the triple product as
$$
\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C} = 
\boldsymbol{B}(\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{C})-\boldsymbol{C}(\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{B})
%![eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiEle.gif)
$$
which should be faster.

So for the first term in python I'm doing

```
import numpy as np

N = 50   #  band index
v = 3    # direction x,y,z
g = 30000 # real space grid points

a = np.ones((N,v,g), dtype = 'complex')
b = np.ones((N,v,g), dtype = 'complex')
c = np.ones((v,g), dtype = 'complex')
H_vnn = np.zeros((N,v,N), dtype = 'complex')

for i in range(g):
         H_vnn += np.array([c[v,i]*(np.dot(a[:,:,i],b[:,:,i].T)) for v in range(3)])
```

which, when doesnt run into memory error, takes forever. Im pretty sure this is not the most efficient way of doing it, but the only alternative I can think of is looping over the g index which seems to be even more expansive. Thank to everybody and particular to those who can help me

Comment: where does the integration come in? It looks you're just summing over $n$ and $m$. So should your first equation not just be a double sum?

Comment: Ops you are right; i have written the wrong code. Instead of the double for loop, is one single loop:  for i in range(g):

Comment: It may be worth taking a look at `numpy.einsum`. (I do not have time for more than this hint or checking whether it actually applies here.)

Comment: In your code, the sub-expression `(np.dot(a[:,:,i],b[:,:,i].T)` does not depend on `v`, so could be pre-computed. And, of course (if you use `C`-ordering of indices), the index `i` is the fastest running index in `a[:,:,i]` or `b[:,:,i]`, so your dot product is over the slower indices, implying extremely inefficient memory access (cache misses all the time). Thus suggests to re-order the indices for `a` and `b` as in `a = np.ones((g,N,v), dtype = 'complex')` (and change the code accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import numpy as np

N = 50   #  band index
v = 3    # direction x,y,z
g = 30000 # real space grid points

a = np.ones((g,N,v), dtype = 'complex')
b = np.ones((g,N,v), dtype = 'complex')
c = np.ones((g,v), dtype = 'complex')
H_vnn = np.zeros((N,v,N), dtype = 'complex')

for i in range(g):
    adotb  = np.dot(a[i,:,:],b[i,:,:].T)
    H_vnn += np.array([c[i,v]*adotb) for v in range(3)])
```

Comment: It improves speed indeed, not as much as I expected but thank you very much!

Comment: How much then? (btw, I appreciate an up-vote or acceptance tick) Also, are you sure the `.T` does actually what you want?

Comment: At least I don't get a memory error anymore so thank you a lot!  I am now focusing on optimizing the problem I am working on so to not have all this massive workload, if i find some good hints I will write them here. Anyway, yes, this is what I was looking for